# Transfer VLAN tagged packets over WLAN?

Tags: firewall, vlan, bridge, wlan

I have the following composition of devices:

```
[selfmade router] - ethernet - [WLAN router 1] ----- wlan ------ [WLAN router 2]
```

`WLAN router 2` has 5 ethernet ports, each as an own VLAN, so 5 VLANs. I want to manage the routing and firewalling between those VLANs at `selfmade router`. What technique would I use to pass the tagged vlan packets from `WLAN router 2` to `selfmade router`?

Could I use a bridge from `WLAN router 2` to `WLAN router 1` which itself has a bridge from `WLAN router 1` to `selfmade router` or do I have a wrong understanding of a bridge?

Thanks for any hint on this :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bridges can/will forward packets between `WLAN router 2` and `selfmade router`, but WDS must be set up on 802.11 (WLAN) link for it to be bridgeable (otherwise WLAN device acting as station (wireless client) won't be able to send/receive packets from MAC addresses connected to it's wired interface(s)).
Remember that you have to set up 2 bridges - on `WLAN router 1` (between it's wired and wireless interfaces) and `WLAN router 2` (between it's wireless interface and (pseudo)interface that acts as trunk-link for 5 VLANs on its ethernet ports).

Comment: yet didn't have the chance to configure all these things, but just wanted to say thanks for your reply, should help me very much :-)